# What is the type of 'then' function parameter in cypress?

Tags: cypress

What is the type of 'e', or is it ok  to leave it as 'any'?

```
cy.get('invoice-date').then((e: any) => e.val(newInvoice.date));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the best explaination but referring to `cypress.d.ts` [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/67183f16706dfa6606f42838cd42064e3c46bcfa/cli/types/cypress.d.ts#L1964) all definitions for the `.then()` callback function are

```js
fn: (this: ObjectLike, currentSubject: Subject) => Chainable<S>
```

where your `e` parameter is `currentSubject: Subject`,

and where `Subject` is defined [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/67183f16706dfa6606f42838cd42064e3c46bcfa/cli/types/cypress.d.ts#L669)

```js
interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
  ...
```

so `any` is ultimately the defined type for that parameter.

Since your particular Subject is a jQuery-wrapped `<input>` element, you may want to use

```js
(e: JQuery<HTMLInputElement>)
```

to give type checking on the code inside the callback.